# Entity Framework get linked entities (faster result)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a SQL database with several tables which are linked together.

"Project" table: Contains informations about projects

"Release" table: Contains informations about releases which are related to projects (one project -> multiple releases; one release -> one project)

"IssuesSW" table: Contains informations about issues which are related to releases (one issueSW -> linked in multiple releases; one release -> contains multiple issuesSW)

In my first solution I just returned the full list of about 10.000 issues but for additional filtering options (based on the projects/releases the issues depends on) I need additional data from the projects and the releases.

The first solution I had took about 2 seconds until the request (and the drawing of some charts on the front end) finished but with the additional data I had to start on the project level and go down till I reach the issues and that takes much too long now.

In my current solution I just used foreach loops to go threw the projects and find their releases and then go threw the releases and find all the issues:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetReleasesWithIsws()
    {
        using (var db = new SwMetricsContext())
        {
            var result = new List<GetCustomerReleasesWithIswsResult>();

            var projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            foreach (var project in projects)
            {
                var releases = db.PVERs.Where(x => x.Project_ID == project.ID).ToList(); 
                foreach(var release in releases)
                {
                    var pver_result = new GetCustomerReleasesWithIswsResult()
                    {
                        Project_Id = project.ID,
                        Project_Title = project.Title,
                        Project_Generation = project.Generation,
                        Project_DefaultDevelopmentMethod = project.DefaultDevelopmentMethod,
                        Release_Id = release.ID,
                        Release_Category = release.Category,
                        Release_Classification = release.Classification,
                        Release_Department = project.ResponsibleAtBosch,
                        Release_ImplementationFreeze = release.ImplementationFreeze,
                        Release_LifeCycleState = release.LifeCycleState,
                        Release_PlannedDate = release.PlannedDate,
                        Release_SpecificationFreeze = release.SpecificationFreeze,
                        Release_Title = release.Title,
                        Release_Type = release.Type
                    };
                    var isw_connections = db.PVERIssuesSW.Where(x => x.Release_ID == release.ID).ToList().Select(x => x.IssueSW_ID).ToHashSet();
                    var isws = db.IssuesSW.Where(x => isw_connections.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
                    pver_result.Release_Isws.AddRange(isws);

                    result.Add(pver_result);
                }
            }
            var json = Json(result);
            json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return json;
        }
    }
```

But the problem with this solution is it takes much too long (about 30 seconds). 
So if someone has a better solution for me I would be very thankful :)

Here are the 3 database table models:

```
[Table("DGSIT_SWMetrics_Projects")]
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
    public string Responsible { get; set; }
    public string DefaultDevelopmentMethod { get; set; }
    public string Generation { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string SpjmName { get; set; }
}

[Table("DGSIT_SWMetrics_PVERs")]
public class Pver  // Release 
{

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Project_ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PlannedDate { get; set; }
    public string ImplementationFreeze { get; set; }
    public string SpecificationFreeze { get; set; }
    public string LifeCycleState { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Classification { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

[Table("DGSIT_SWMetrics_IssuesSW")]
public class IssueSW
{
    public string Project_ID { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string LCS { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string DevelopmentMethod { get; set; }
    public string Allocation { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public string ExternalReview { get; set; }
    public int Assignee_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

IssueSW has it´s own "Project_ID" because it depends on one "Cluster-Project". But it´s also linked to the Releases with an extra table:

```
[Table("DGSIT_SWMetrics_PVERIssuesSW")]
public class PVERIssueSw
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Release_ID { get; set; }
    public string IssueSW_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This just looks ... not right usage of EF. Don't you have navigation properties in the entity model?

Comment: *In my first solution* - solution of what? It's quite hard to find a better solution for a problem you don't describe.

Comment: Since we don't know what your expected result is, or anything about your data structure, we can't really suggest much.

Comment: @IvanStoev I´ve tried to add the navigation properties and then just use .Include() but the problem is not all projects are saved in this database (it´s just the combination of a view external databases) and some releases are pointing to projects which are not included in the database. Entity Framework gave me errors when I tried to add releasees without an existing project. Is there a way to set the properties to "not needed" or something like that?

Comment: @ADyson I´ve added a few more informations to the original post. If you need any more information please just ask me. Thanks for your time!